# Any thoughts im having an error updating npm fsevent

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, netlify

```
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
> npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
```

Any thoughts? I'm installing Netlify in my visual code.

Comment: Those are *warnings*; what's the actual error?

Comment: thats the warning, thats the actual error. i need to update fsevents. but i cant see anyway how.